# Multi-step form issues in Node Js and Express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

What is the best practice for creating multistep forms in Node.js and Express currently i am using the following approach:

```
app.post('/new/beer', function(req, res) {
  // Step one
  if (req.session.currentAction.step == 1) {
     req.session.currentAction.step = 2;
     res.render('beer-step-1');
  }
  // Step two
  if (req.session.currentAction.step == 2) {
     req.session.currentAction.step = 3;
     res.render('beer-step-2');
  }
  // Step three
  if (req.session.currentAction.step == 3) {
     req.session.currentAction.step = 4;
     res.render('beer-step-3');
  }
});
```

I think my problem is obvious from the code above. No matter what the original step value is the post request is always reaching and rendering the beer-step-3 template.

Am I approaching the multi-step form in the wrong way? Or is there a way to end the request at a certain point?

Comment: Add a return after each res.render('whatever');

Comment: This has worked and does seem like an obvious solution, but i'm not sure if its is the correct way to do it, I would have expected there to be a safer node/express style way of ending the request. I'll go with this for now through.

Answer (score 0):

The currently you are using the req.session.currentAction, which might not be initialized as object. You have to add the check or initialize the object. Without this you expose potential bug when you are requesting page without the session var set. Make sure you use the === comparison.

Also why not store the form step as URL parameter ?

Comment: I could use parameters or query's but i feel as though that could be open to exploitation and user manipulation. P.S I know my snippet of code doesn't show it but the req.session.currentAction object definitely exists at this point.